# What is the Usage (Hours) in OpenStack's web interface Horizon CSV Summary and why most of my instances have the same value (17.02)?

Tags: openstack

In OpenStack's web interface Horizon, under Project Overview we can download a CSV Summary.

[image]

I am surprised to see that in the CSV summary I downloaded, the `Usage (Hours)` column is almost always 17.02. What is Usage (Hours) supposed to quantify, and what can explain that most of my instances have the same value (17.02)?

[image]

The [official documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/content/track_usage.html) doesn't seem to give any explanation

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: Since this question received no answer, I posted it on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-is-the-Usage-Hours-in-OpenStacks-web-interface-Horizon-CSV-Summary-and-why-most-of-my-instances-have-the-same-value-17-02